# Bluetooth on Windows Server 2012

Tags: bluetooth, windows-server-2012

I am looking for a way to get Bluetooth going on Windows Server 2012

I am running on a Lenovo ThinkPad. I have downloaded the drivers, which throw an error when you first install them via the .exe, but run ok if you open the .msi in the x64 folder, that is until the last state when it complains about a missing .cpl file.

Is there a simpler way of getting the drivers without having to modify .inf files?

Answer (score -1):

Install the Hotkey utility from the Lenovo website. Then press F5 and turn on the Bluetooth radio. Windows will detect the device and install a basic driver automatically. I haven't tried the Lenovo-supplied drivers yet, which add a few additional profiles. This worked on my X61s.

Comment: -1 Windows server lacks the bth.inf file which provides the “basic support”.

Comment: There obviously talking about a workaround, why down vote that? Check out this link  http://www.capitalhead.com/articles/enable--install-microsoft-bluetooth-stack-on-windows-server-2008-x64.aspx